# navigation.navigate does not work in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am creating filter page screen.. On this screen once i fill all the data on which i wanted to filter the data i will click on save button and that will redirect me to the home page where my new filtered data will be displayed.My home page already showing the general data but if i wanted to see filter data then i will filter that data from filter screen.
But here i have problem is i am not able to redirect to the home page. the code which i am using for redirection is same for whole my application which is working perfectly alright.I only have problem with redirecting to home page and there no error displayed in the console but  is prints the message i have written in my function. Rather than nothing is doing.

```
import NavigationService from '../../components/NavigationService';
    onSaveClicked() {

        console.log('Filter is in progress');
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.navigate('home');
        const { userprofile } = this.props;
        const  { type } = userprofile;
        NavigationService.navigate('HomeStackScreen1', {type:type});


      }
  renderButton() {
    return (
      <Button
        style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
        onPress={this.onSaveClicked.bind(this)}
      >
        Filter
      </Button>
    );
  }
```

navigationService.js

```
    import { NavigationActions,navigation } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params
    })
  );
}

function getParams(param){
  console.log("param: "+param);
  _navigator.dispatch(
    console.log("param: "+param),
    navigation.getParam(param)
  );
}


export default { setTopLevelNavigator, navigate, getParams };
```

Navigation stack :

```
    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeStackScreen1: {
      screen: DrawerNavigation,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Action',
        headerLeft: (
          <DrawerButton name="navicon" style={styles.Headercss} navigation={navigation} />
        ),
        headerRight: (
          <SearchButton style={styles.Headercss} navigation={navigation} />
        ),
        //headerStyle: { paddingRight: 5, paddingLeft: 5 },
        headerTitleStyle: { color: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)' }

      })
    },
    Project: {
      screen: ProjectTab,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: '  Create New Project',
        headerTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)', 
      })
    },
    Notification: {
      screen: NotificationScreen
    },
    Filters: {
     screen: FilterScreen,
     navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: 'Filter',
      headerTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)', 
    })
    },
    UpdateProfile: {
      screen:UserProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'Profile',
        headerTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)', 
      })
    },
    ViewActorProfile: {
      screen: ViewActorProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'View Profile',
        headerTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)', 
      })
    },
    ViewProducer :{
      screen: ViewProducerProfile,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'View Profile',
        headerTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)', 
      })
    },
    ProjectView: {
      screen: ViewProject,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'View Project',
        headerTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)', 
      })
    },
    AppliedProjectScreen: {
      screen: AppliedProjectUsers,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'Applied Users',
        headerTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)', 
      })
    },
    ChattingScreen: {
      screen: Chat,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Chat'
      }
    },
    ViewActorProfileScreen: {
      screen: ViewActorProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'View Profile',
        headerTintColor: 'rgb(234, 94, 32)',
      })
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeStackScreen1',
    headerMode: 'screen'
  }
);
```

Comment: Is NavigationService.navigate('Home') working ? Also,  can you use back() ?

Comment: Can you post your `Navigation Stack` file, where home is being registered?

Comment: @JulienMalige no NavigationService.navigate('Home') is not working. i havent tried back() yet but i m working on it right now

Comment: as @PritishVaidya said, posting your `post your Navigation Stack` can help.

Comment: yes i have updated the code please check and let me know. and yes goBack() is workng properly but i also wanted to send data to home page which would be my filtered data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the exact home route name as navigate param:

`navigation.navigate('HomeStackScreen1');`

If you want, you also can rename `HomeStackScreen1` to `Home` on your Navigation Stack.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html

Comment: yes its working but  'navigation.navigate('Home');' this should also worked because i have already use it before and i didnt find any problem with that

Comment: maybe you had another route called `home` in your stack or you just renamed it. `Navigate()` just uses keys.

Comment: @MahiParmar if my answer fixed your issue, thanks to accept it :)

Comment: i have another confusion how to pass params from filter screen and retrievd it on homepage

Comment: You will find all answers in the doc... https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Comment: If you build a filter, I will suggest you to pass a setState ref as prop : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/288#issuecomment-315684617

Comment: thanks Juilen for the reference i have tried the solution written on docs but i m still getting error "cannot read property 'getParam' of undefined